# Inline IF statement in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, case

I've been breaking my head for a couple of days now and can't find a way to achieve what I'm trying to do (I've searched all over the web!). I have tried with WHERE clauses, nested IF and CASE functions to no avail.

I have a table with information about models. The info includes a field named "country" which is where they actually live. There is also a field called "hideme" which can be a 1 if they do not want to appear on the search results of persons from that country, and a 0 otherwise. I'm getting the visitor's country with MaxMind's GeoIP DB.

So this is what I want, more clearly said: if the visitor if from let's say US, and the model is from the US and the "hideme" field is 1, she should not appear on the results. I have no problem with PHP or getting the country code, just the correct SELECT statement.

Here is my code so far:

```
$select = "SELECT user
       IF (country != '$country_id', country,
           IF (hideme = 1, 1, 0))
       FROM models";

$result = mysql_query($select);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row[user];
}
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM models WHERE country=$country_id AND hideme=0` ?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: @andrewsi What if she has a hideme=1 but from a different country?

Comment: @AdanVasconcelos - have a look at GolezTrol's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  user
FROM
  models
WHERE
  country != '$country_id' /* Those from another country */
  OR hideme = 0 /* .. or allowed to view, regardless of country */
```

This returns the models that are either from another country, or have hideme set to 0. This is implicitly the same as saying to return models except those that are from the same country and having hideme set to 1, so alternatively you could change the where to:

```
SELECT 
  user
FROM
  models
WHERE
  NOT ( /* Except ... */
    country = '$country_id' /* .. those that are from the same country */
    AND hideme = 1 /* .. and having hideme set to 1. */
  )
```

The latter is a little harder to read, but matches more closely with the textual description. The results are the same, assuming you haven't got records that have value NULL for either country or hideme.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a WHERE clause

```
SELECT user
FROM   models
WHERE NOT (country = '$country_id' AND hideme)
```

Comment: Mark, that gives me only models matching the visitor's country, and if I negate that !=, I don't get those matching the country but without the hideme on.

Comment: @AdanVasconcelos: I think I worked out what your question means now, but it wasn't very clear at all. You should try to make your questions clear. Provide sample data and show what result you want.

Comment: Thanks Mark. This was my first post. I'll try to be more clear next time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't understand your question right, but isn't it just:

```
SELECT user FROM models WHERE country = '$country_id' AND hideme = 0
```